# скрипт галлереи

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, привожу скрипт загрузки на страницу простенькой галереи. Не могу разобраться с директорией.

```
<?php
// Если upload файла 
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"])) 
{ 
$myfile = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]; 
$myfile_name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]; 
$myfile_size = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"]; 
$myfile_type = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"]; 
$error_flag = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

// Если ошибок не было 
if($error_flag == 0) 
{

$f_thum="./gallery/thum_" . $myfile_name;

print("Имя файла на нашем сервере (во время запроса): ".$myfile."<br>"); 
print("Имя файла на компьютере пользователя: ".$myfile_name."<br>");
print("Имя файла на сервере: ".$f."<br>");
print("Имя thumb-файла на сервере: ".$f_thum."<br>");
print("MIME-тип файла: ".$myfile_type."<br>"); 
print("Размер файла: ".$myfile_size."<br><br>");

// если размер файла больше 512 Кб
if ($myfile_size > 512*1024) die('Размер файла больше 512 Кб! Уменьшите файл и повторите попытку');

// копируем 
copy($myfile,"./gallery/$myfile_name");

// делаем thumb
function imageresize($outfile,$infile,$neww,$newh,$quality) {

    $im=imagecreatefromjpeg($infile); 
    $im1=imagecreatetruecolor($neww,$newh); 
    imagecopyresampled($im1,$im,0,0,0,0,$neww,$newh,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));

    imagejpeg($im1,$outfile,$quality); 
    imagedestroy($im); 
    imagedestroy($im1); 
}

// создаем миниатюру размером 160х100, качество JPEG 75
imageresize($f_thum,"./gallery/$myfile_name",160,100,75);

} 
}
else 
{
    // выводим форму
    echo file_get_contents('gallery_form.html');
}

?>

а это скрипт просмотра галереи
?php

$dir = "./gallery";
$N = 3;         // количество картинок в строке

echo "<h1>Галерея</h1><p><table width=100$ cols=$N>";

$i = 0;         // счетчик итераций

// получаем все элементы каталога gallery в массив images
$images = scandir($dir);

// выводим таблицу с картинками
foreach ($images as $k=>$v)
{
// выводим только миниатюры и ссылки на большие изображения
if (strpos($v,"thum_")!==false)
    {
        if ($i % $N == 0) echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        $image = substr($v, 5);    
        echo "<a target=_blank href=\"$dir//$image\"><img border=0 src=\"$dir//$v\"></a>";

// выводим названия картинок в полях text и кнопку удалить    
echo "<form action=\"router.php\" method=post>
<input name=del type=text readonly=true value=\"$image\" />
<input name=del type=text readonly=true value=\"$v\" />
<input name=submit type=submit value=delete />
</form>";
            echo "</td>";
            $i++;
        }

}

echo "</table>";

echo file_get_contents('gallery_form.html');

?>
```

Comment: Переводить ошибки религия запрещает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
copy($myfile,"localhost/gallery/$myfile_name");
//исправить на:
copy($myfile,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gallery/$myfile_name");
//как в принципе и везде далее
вместо localhost пользуем $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Comment: при просмотре картинки не показывает картинку и вылезает табличка
"Firefox не может определить, как открыть данный адрес, так как протокол (z) не связан ни с одним приложением."

Comment: Вместо $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] заменил на ./gallery - заработало.
Теперь буду думать над надписями к картинкам и функцию удаления.

Comment: это скрипт обработчика удаления картинок из галереи.Названия передаются через поле 'text' посредством POST.Сверяеться имя файла и удаляеться. Вот вопрос: как осуществить запрос на удаление кнопками да и нет и удалять? Заранее благодарен)
<?php

$dir = "./gallery";

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$name=$_POST['del'];

    unlink ($dir.'/'.$name);
    print 'Удален файл' . $name;
}

?>

Comment: Сергей, создайте новый вопрос